# how to combine common values from 2 txt files into 1 file using python

Tags: python, io

I'm not sure how to write a script to combine values in 2 separate txt files using the specific tag of `not done` and ensure there are no duplicates. I currently have 2 files with lists of filenames.

Each of them have 'tags' that indicate whether they 'exist' or not.

Here is an example:

File1.txt:

> P03T10C01  ...[not done]
> P02T02C03...exists
> P12T06C04...exists
> P02T02C06...exists
> P06T09C01...exists
> P03T19C04  ...[not done]
> P04T08C01  ...[not done]

File2.txt:

> P15T05C05  ...[not done]
> P15T05C04...exists
> P03T10C01  ...[not done]
> P12T06C04...exists
> P06T09C01...exists
> P03T19C05  ...[not done]
> P03T19C04  ...[not done]

Since the values

> "P03T10C01"  and "P03T19C04 "
> are common in both files, it should appear in my `result.txt` once. The others that have `[not done]` attached to it, should also be in the `result.txt`.

Result.txt:

> P03T19C04  ...[not done]
> P04T08C01  ...[not done]
> P03T10C01  ...[not done]
> P03T19C05  ...[not done]
> P15T05C05  ...[not done]

How does a script for this look like? Any help is appreciated thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below script will read the textfiles, find the common elements and write it on another file

```py
txt1, txt2 = '', ''
with open("path/to/txtfile1.txt", "r") as f1:
    txt1 = f1.read()
with open("path/to/txtfile2.txt", "r") as f2:
    txt2 = f2.read()

txtlist1 = [x for x in txt1.split("\n") if "not done" in x]
txtlist2 = [x for x in txt2.split("\n") if "not done" in x]
print(len(txtlist1), len(txtlist2))

set1 = set(txtlist1)
set2 = set(txtlist2)
result = '\n'.join(list(set1.union(set2)))

with open("path/to/txtfile3.txt", "w") as f3:
    f3.write(result)
```

Result

```
P03T10C01 ...[not done]
P03T19C04 ...[not done]
P03T19C05 ...[not done]
P04T08C01 ...[not done]
P15T05C05 ...[not done]
```